# Does iOS8 allow us to have our own quick replies?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

We have own messaging app and I am wondering if the new iOS8 functionality allows us to create our own quick reply? So just like I can quick reply a SMS, we'd like to do it with our app. Is it possible?

Comment: Not sure why people are downvoting this, as it's a perfectly valid question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the documentation/devforums it appears not. Developers have access to interactive notifications (eg, adding buttons to their notifications when a user swipes down), but it doesn't look like we can implement anything like the quick reply feature for Messages.app. :(.

[Source](https://devforums.apple.com/message/998172#998172) on the devforums (requires an ADC account to access).